# Left outer join on 2 columns not running properly

Tags: sql, heidisql

**a** is a table of 5,000,000 records and a score. **b** is a table of 100,000 records and a (different) score. I want to output every record from table **a** as long as the same record is not in table **b** with a score equal to 1.

The following query I wrote has taken 15 hours to execute and is still running. Is it possible that it could take this long to do such a query or is there perhaps something wrong with my code?

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.score
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.c1=b.c1
AND a.c2=b.c2
WHERE b.score <> 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query retrieves all records from table a that are also in table b with a score not equal to 1 (and it retrieves those records as many times as they appear in table b with a score other than 1).
Which is different from "every record from table a as long as the same record is not in table b with a score equal to 1".

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.score
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM b
    WHERE a.c1 = b.c1
    AND a.c2 = b.c2
    AND b.score = 1
)
```

The query above can take advantage of the following index

```
create index my_idx on b(c1,c2,score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve his in different ways.

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.score
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM b WHERE  a.c1=b.c1
AND a.c2=b.c2 and b.score = 1)
```

OR

```
  SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.score
    INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
    FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM a  INNER JOIN b 
ON a.c1=b.c1
AND a.c2=b.c2 and b.score =1 )
```

ANOTHER WAY

```
;with t as 
(
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.score from a 
),
u as 
(
select * FROM b where score =1 and b.c2=t.c2 and b.c1 = t.c1
)
SELECT t.c1,t.c2,t.score FROm t INTO OUTPUT 'FILe.csv WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  u)
```

You can use In as well, but this may have a performance issue.
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_exists.php